# Error C2371 while trying to in instantiate a template with std::function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

Consider the following C++ Program

```
#include <cwchar>
#include <cwctype>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
template <typename Ty>
struct Tokenize {
    Ty m_delim;
    Tokenize(Ty& delim):m_delim(delim){}
};

int main() {
    std::function<bool (wchar_t)> foo = iswdigit; //Compiles fine
    Tokenize<std::string >(std::string("")); //Compiles fine
    Tokenize<std::function<bool (wchar_t)> >(foo); // Fails
    return 0;
}
```

On Trying to compile with VC++, fails with compiler Error

```
error C2371: 'foo' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2512: 'Tokenize<Ty>' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

Looks like it tries to redefine foo, but no clue what so ever how

**Note** A close scrutiny reveals that the compiler consides

```
Tokenize<std::function<bool (wchar_t)> >(foo)
```

as constructing an object of type `Tokenize<std::function<bool (wchar_t)> >` with default parameters, i.e.

```
Tokenize<std::function<bool (wchar_t)> >  foo
```

but the question remains why?

Comment: Note that you should also be getting a compiler error for passing a `std::string` as a non-const reference to the `Tokenize` constructor. VC++ is not standard conforming in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're used to seeing code like:

```
T(arg1, arg2)
```

in order to create a *temporary* of type `T`. You're used to seeing this in expressions, such as:

```
f(T(arg1, arg2))
```

You have also seen it with one argument:

```
f(T(arg1))
```

However, when your supposed temporary creation is the *full* statement on a line of code, it is syntactically indistinguishable from a declaration.

That is:

```
T(arg1);
```

is the same as:

```
T arg1;
```

Where a piece of code may be a declaration *or* an expression, it is always an declaration. This is essentially an example of the [**most vexing parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You may use `()` to disambiguate, forcing the statement to read as an expression:

```
(T(arg1));
```

But then I would generally ask why you feel the need to create a temporary on its own line that you then do nothing with.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "it is always a declaration"?

Comment: @enobayram: Er, yes. It should. :)

Comment: "But then I would generally ask why you feel the need to create a temporary on its own line that you then do nothing with." .. off course because it is the re-creatable minimal failing code.

Comment: @Abhijit: But hopefully it doesn't play a part in the "practical problem that you are trying to solve", as it is a design smell. You can't come up with a practically useful question about poor code that you wouldn't use in real life that only exists due to the process of presenting a testcase for the question.. that's circular!

Answer (score 1):

You want to define an object, don't you?

Then, `Tokenize<std::function<bool (wchar_t)> >(foo);` should be `Tokenize<std::function<bool (wchar_t)> > tokenizer(foo);`

Comment: But the Synatx is fine for creating a temporary object? For example `Tokenize<std::string >(std::string(""));` is a completly legitimate code?

Comment: @Abhijit Yes. But `std::string s(""); Tokenize<std::string>(s);` is not again :). It depends on the context.